# Legendre's Series: How can I show that $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)S(x)dx= f(1)$

Tags: mathematical-physics, legendre-polynomials

Consider the series:

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)P_n(x)}{2}$$

Show that:

$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)S(x)dx= f(1)$$

where $f(x)$ is any function of the interval $[−1, 1]$ on the real numbers which can be expressed as a series of Legendre polynomials.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your work. This site is not a homework solving service.

Comment: Hi Gary, sorry. I forgot to write my attempt at resolution. It's my fisrt time using this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ can be expressed as a series of [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials):
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nP_n(x). \tag{1}
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)S(x)\,dx&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\int_{-1}^{1}P_n(x)S(x)\,dx \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{2m+1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}P_n(x)P_m(x)\,dx \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n, \tag{2}
\end{align}
where the last equality follows from the [orthogonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality_and_completeness) and normalization of the Legendre polynomials,
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}P_n(x)P_m(x)\,dx=\frac{2}{2m+1}\,\delta_{nm}. \tag{3}
$$
Since [$P_n(1)=1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Additional_properties_of_Legendre_polynomials), it follows from $(1)$ that $f(1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$. Comparing this result with $(2)$, we conclude that
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)S(x)\,dx=f(1). \tag{4}
$$

Comment: According to [site regulations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) answering questions without context or where the OP didn't show their own effort should be avoided.